# Fetching JSON via AJAX from database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

My code is not working. Can anyone tell me what's wrong with it? I don't get any result from this code. Please help.

```
<a href="" id="navigation-edit">EDIT MENU</a>
```

```js
$(function(){
    $("a#navigation-edit").on(("click"),function(){ 
         $.getJSON("ajax/navigation-edit.php", function(data) {
             $("#result").html(data);
        });              
    });
});
```

> navigation-edit.php

```
 <?PHP

$result_NavDel = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM navigation_dynamic");
while($row = $result_NavDel->fetch_assoc()){
    $data[] = "<li class='animated bounce infinite'><a  href='?".$row['url']."'>".$row['menu']."</a></li>";

}

$implode='<ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="deleteNav">'`.`implode($data).'</ul>';
 echo json_encode($implode);




 ?>
```

Comment: That html is invalid. Also doesn't represent `$("a#navigation-edit")` in any way

Comment: Hi sorry, in html i mean <a href="" id="navigation-edit">EDIT MENU</a>

Comment: Update the question then if it is a mistake.

Comment: `json_encode("ok");` will result in invalid json, so your `getJSON` will fail - hopefully you're encoding something in PHP that will produce **valid** json

Comment: Does the code execute $("a#navigation-edit").on(("click"),function(){  ?

Comment: Change to `$.get()` instead of `$.getJSON()` since you aren't wanting json

Comment: Hmm, i edited my in php coding,

Answer (score 0):

You are making a request asking for JSON formatted response when you use `$.getJSON()`.

However it is clear from intent of your php and callback code you only want `text/html` returned so just change from using `$.getJSON()` to using `$.get()` which will default to `text/html`

---

If you do want JSON then change to something like:

PHP

```
$data=array('text'=>'OK');
echo json_encode($data);
```

And change callback of `$.getJSON to:

```
$.getJSON("ajax/navigation-edit.php", function(data) {
     $("#result").html(data.text);
});
```